# n linear independent set of n-times continuously differentiable function on an open interval forms a n-th order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\{\varphi_1(t),\varphi_2(t),\varphi_3(t),\dots,\varphi_n(t)\}$ be a linear independent set of $n$-times continuously differentiable functions on an open interval  $I\subset\mathbb R$.

How can I show that there exists a set of continous functions $p_{n-1}(t),\dots,p_1(t),p_0(t)$ on $I$ such that

$\varphi_j^{(n)}(t)+p_{n-1}(t)\varphi_j^{n-1}(t)+\dots+p_1(t)\varphi_j'(t)+p_0(t)\varphi_j(t)=0$

on $I$, for every $j=1,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: I think you need to assume more than that, e.g., the Wronskian $W(\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n)$ does not vanish on $I$.  Then expand the ratio of Wronskians
$$
\frac{W(\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_n,y)(t)}{W(\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_n)(t)}
=
\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
\phi_1(t)& \phi_2(t) & \dots & \phi_n(t) & y(t)\\
\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t) & \dots & \phi_n'(t) & y'(t)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\phi_1^{(n)}(t) & \phi_2^{(n)}(t) & \dots & \phi_n^{(n)}(t) & y^{(n)}(t)\\
\end{vmatrix}
}{
\begin{vmatrix}
\phi_1(t)& \phi_2(t) & \dots & \phi_n(t)\\
\phi_1'(t) & \phi_2'(t) & \dots & \phi_n'(t)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\phi_1^{(n-1)}(t) & \phi_2^{(n-1)}(t) & \dots & \phi_n^{(n-1)}(t)\\
\end{vmatrix}
}
$$
which is $0$ if $y$ is one of the $\phi_j$, and the coefficient of $y^{(n)}(t)$ is unity.

---

**Example**: For $n=1$, you are asserting $\phi_1'(t)+p_0(t)\phi_1(t)=0$ for some continuous $p_0(t)$.  But this obviously fails at any point $t$ where $\phi_1(t)=0$ but $\phi_1'(t)\neq 0$.